# How to put therefore and implies symbols

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
\textbf{THEOREM :} If an operator has both Left Identity and Right Identity then it is \emph{UNIQUE}.
\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
\textbf{PROOF :} Let e_{l} is left identity 
                         therefore e_{l} * e_{r} 
                             this implies e_{r}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It would be nice, if you could explain, what you tried to include the symbols, where they should appear, and whether you need that in more than this small example (because then maybe it's better to use `algorithm2e` or something like that).

Comment: i want to write symbol for "therefore"

Comment: If you are using `\vspace` font changes or `\noindent` in a document it is a sign that something is probably wrong. Ideally the markup should just be `\begin{theorem}` with the spacing and fonts specified elsewhere.

Comment: the three dots symbol is `$\therefore$` (amssymb package) see `texdoc symbols`

Answer (score 46):

As stated in the comments, you get the symbols in mathmode simply by writing them down. Packages like `amsmath` and `amssymb` support you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
If an operator has both Left Identity and
Right Identity then it is \emph{UNIQUE}.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Let $e_{l}$ is left identity 
$\therefore e_{l} * e_{r} \implies e_{r}$
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With a very fierce “don't do it in a printed document”!

Comment: I think you're missing an `amsthm` somewhere.

Comment: @kahen Can you explain why? Did you run my example?

Comment: Whats the difference between \usepackage{amsmath} and \usepackage{amssymb}?

Comment: @user71207 math is for maths, symb is for symbols.

Comment: I see thanks. Does the "ams" mean anything specific or is it just randomly there? What differs "maths" from "symbols"?

Comment: @user71207 The AMS is the American Mathematical Society.

Answer (score 5):

A somewhat larger version of `\therefore` may be built as:

```
\dot{.\hspace{.095in}.}\hspace{.5in}
```

Comparison traditional and larger version:

[image]

Comment: That sort of tricks may be OK for visual rendering but they can be highly undesirable when trying to copy raw text from a generated PDF

Answer (score 4):

Initialisation Code:

```
\def\therefore{\boldsymbol{\text{ }
\leavevmode
\lower0.4ex\hbox{$\cdot$}
\kern-.5em\raise0.7ex\hbox{$\cdot$}
\kern-0.55em\lower0.4ex\hbox{$\cdot$}
\thinspace\text{ }}}
```

And can then be called on using:

```
\therefore
```

Which renders as:

[image: RENDERED THEREFORE]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could simply use `lualatex` and a font which actually has the character:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Brill}% just an example -- download at http://www.brill.com/about/brill-fonts
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
If an operator has both Left Identity and
Right Identity then it is \emph{UNIQUE}.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Let $e_{l}$ is left identity 
∴ $e_{l} * e_{r}$ ⇒ $e_{r}$
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely happy with any of the handmade `therefore`'s proposed above, I thought I would offer this one also that, in my opinion, has a good balance of dot size (in between `\bullet` and `\cdot`) and spacing:

```
\def\therefore{{\tiny$\bullet$}\kern-0.2ex\raisebox{1ex}{\tiny$\bullet$}\kern-0.2ex{\tiny$\bullet$}}
```

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: you might want to share a rendering of it...

Comment: Add  rendering example, I also prefer a bolder therefore

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
\textbf{THEOREM :} If an operator has both Left Identity and Right Identity then it is \emph{UNIQUE}.
\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
\textbf{PROOF :} Let e\_{l} is left identity 
                         $\therefore$ e\_{l} * e\_{r} 
                             $\implies$ e\_{r}
                             $\Rightarrow$ e\_{r}
\end{document}
```

The above code will give you the following result. I have added two "implies" symbol in case one of those looks too long.

[image: preliminary]

A better formatting for the document would be,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} % for adding lemma

\begin{document}
\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
\begin{theorem}
If an operator has both Left Identity and Right Identity then it is \emph{UNIQUE}.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Let $e\_l$ is left identity.
\begin{align*}
    \therefore e_l * e_r \\
    \implies e_r \\
    \Rightarrow e_r
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

which will generate the following.

[image: improved]