# Argument in Discrete Mathematics

Tags: tables, math-mode

This is my code:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
$P(1)$ \\
$P(1)$ \\
$\forall n \in \N ((P(n) \land P(n+1) \implies P(n+2))$ \\
\hline
$\forall n \in \N (P(n))$ \\
\end{tabular}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Pic 1]

I want it to look like this:

[image: Pic 2]

So my question really is, how can I align each line to the left within the tabular. Alternatively, is there a package just for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{l}` where `l` implies "left aligned", whereas your code uses `c` meaning "centered".  Also, your data employ only one column, so that `{llll}` is not needed, only `{l}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Alternatively, is there a package just for this?

Yes, I believe [ebproof](https://ctan.org/pkg/ebproof?lang=en) really fits the bill.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{&P(1)}
    \infer[no rule]1{&P(2)}
    \infer[no rule]1{&\forall n \in \mathbf{N} ((P(n) \land P(n+1) \implies P(n+2))}
    \infer1{& \therefore \forall n \in \mathbf{N} (P(n))}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

The `&` character is here to tune the alignment, there is no need to explicitly declare the math. environment, and the package is flexible enough to accommodate multiple variations.

As a side note, you can get the therefore symbol [using other techniques](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142551/).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Since all material is in math mode, you should use an `array` environment, with a single column of type `l`, instead of a `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,booktabs}
\let\implies\Rightarrow % ? -- maybe '\rightarrow'?
\newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\begin{array}{@{}l@{}} % "@{}" suppresses whitespace padding
P(1) \\
P(2) \\
\forall n \in \N \bigl((P(n) \land P(n+1) \implies P(n+2)\bigr) \\
\midrule % for a well-spaced horizontal rule
\therefore\forall n \in \N (P(n)) 
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have voted all your answers. Very good. +1

Comment: I always think that friendship is a sign of respect, kindness and good manners. When I can always vote for my friends and I think I have written it sometimes.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks, dear friend! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Almost the same solution, but in display mode. I suggest using `booktabs` for horizontal rules, so you have a better vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\NN{\mathbf{N}}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{array}{l}
  P(1) \\
  P(1) \\
  \forall n \in \NN,\bigl(P(n) \land P(n+1) \implies P(n+2)\bigr) \\
\midrule
  \therefore\forall n \in \NN (P(n))
\end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your proof is wrong!!! `;-)`

Comment: Does using a displaymath environment make a meaningful difference? The interior of the `array` environment will be in text-style either way, right?

Comment: @Mico: Of course it doesn't make a real difference.  I only wanted to insist on the use of booktabs to improve the layout. As to the interior of  arrays, that's true,; in general, I favour the use of medsize formulae, as defined by `nccmath` in this case, but there was no element in the O.P.'s code to illustrate this.